# JS Testing and Web3 referencing contract at deployed address

Tags: truffle, javascript, truffle-test

I have a Contract Factory and a sub contract, and now i want to test the newly created sub contract.  This one should be pretty simple, I hope.

```
it("test CoinNewCoin - Test Created Coin ", function (){

    var fromOwner = accounts[0];
    var coinFactory;
    var coinNewCoin;
    return CoinFactory.deployed().then((instance) => {
        coinFactory = instance;
    }).then(() => {
    return coinFactory.getCoinAddress(fromOwner, {from: fromOwner});
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    return CoinNewCoin.at(result).then((instance) => {
    }).then((instance) => {
        console.log(instance); // this is the undefined.
        coinNewCoin = instance;
        return coinNewCoin.getAuthorizationKey();
    })
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

edit: scripting updated.

Comment: `coinFactory.address` on web3 v0.x, and `coinFactory._address` on web3 v1.x.

Comment: could you expound a bit?  maybe something in the form of the newcoin Return?  The factory and call to create a coin work fine, now i want to test the created coin, and i have the address of the coin in the result.

Comment: Maybe change `NewCoin.deployed()` to `NewCoin.at(result)`.

Comment: (thanks for the help btw), the results  
Contract: CoinFactory test state  
    √ test CoinFactory (49ms)   
    √ test CoinNewCoin - Create Coin (63ms)  
 0x74eb9deac37f34457f71adab57fb8bbc6bce3c0a  
undefined  
1) test CoinNewCoin - Test Created Coin  
> No events were emitted 
2 passing (267ms)  
1 failing   1) Contract: CoinFactory test state test CoinNewCoin - Test Created Coin : TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAuthorizationKey' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return CoinNewCoin.at(result).getAuthorizationKey();

The at(address), was the key.  thanks -goodvibration!

```
it("test CoinNewCoin - Test Created Coin ", function (){

    var fromOwner = accounts[0];
    var coinFactory;
    var coinNewCoin;
    var coinAddress;
    return CoinFactory.deployed().then((instance) => {
        coinFactory = instance;
    }).then(() => {
        return coinFactory.getCoinAddress(fromOwner, {from: fromOwner});
    }).then((result) => {
        return CoinNewCoin.at(result).getAuthorizationKey();
    }).then((result) => {
        var testVal = result.toString().split(",");
        assert.equal("00000000000000000000000000000000",web3.toAscii(testVal[0]), "Coin contract is was not created, fail!")
    });
});
```